# Incorrect Test Vectors for AES' MixColumns?

Tags: aes, algorithm-design

I'm looking for test vectors for AES' MixColums and I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns#Test_vectors_for_MixColumn.28.29.3B_not_for_InvMixColumn

Here it says that the operation on the column 1, 1, 1, 1 doesn't do anything and returns 1, 1, 1, 1.

I don't understand this. From MixColumns here's what we're doing:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} \\
\mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{a_0} \\
\mathtt{a_1} \\
\mathtt{a_2} \\
\mathtt{a_3} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And so, $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3$ will be calculated as:

$$
(\mathtt{02} \cdot \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{03} \cdot \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{01} \cdot \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{01} \cdot \mathtt{01})
$$

with:

- $02 * 01$ is $X * 1$ which is $02$
- $03 * 01$ is $(X+1) * 1$ which is $03$
- $01 * 01 = 01$

So the total should be $03 + 02 + 01 + 01 = 07$.

Answer (score 6):

No, $03 + 02 + 01 + 01 = 01$

The problem is that you are misinterpreting $+$, it's not addition modulo 256; instead, it's the addition operation in the field $GF(2^8)$, which can be computed by performing the *exclusive-or* on the inputs.

And, $03 \oplus 02 \oplus 01 \oplus 01 = 01$

Comment: Oups, here this is $(X+1) \oplus X \oplus 1 \oplus 1$ which is indeed $1$.